# Create a triangle out of stars using only recursion

Tags: java, recursion

I need to to write a method that is called like `printTriangle(5);`. We need to create an iterative method and a recursive method (without ANY iteration). The output needs to look like this:

```
*
**
***
****
*****
```

This code works with the iterative but I can't adapt it to be recursive.

```
public void printTriangle (int count) {
    int line = 1;
    while(line <= count) {
        for(int x = 1; x <= line; x++) {
            System.out.print("*");
        }
        System.out.print("\n");
        line++;
    }
}
```

I should note that you cannot use any class level variables or any external methods.

Comment: Is this a homework assignment?

Comment: @DJ. Yes it is. This is the first time in 22 chapters I have had any problem.

@mobrule: What does that have to do with anything?

One thing I tried was using formatted string, but it seems like Java doesn't support custom padding characters.

Comment: Why do you combine a while loop and for loop in the iterative version?  It will look much cleaner (and maybe be easier to convert to recursion) with two nested for loops).

Comment: I could, but my professor says he wants clarity over performance (I think he is just lazy).

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2498039/printing-a-sideways-triangle-in-java/2498161#2498161

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Notice in your iterative approach that you have two counters: the first is what line you are on `line`, and the second is what position on the line you are on `x`.  You could create a recursive function that takes two parameters and uses them as nested counters, `y` and `x`.  Where you decrement x until it reaches 0, then decrement y and set x = y, until both x and y are 0.

You could also notice that each successive line in the triangle is the previous line plus one star.  If your recursive function returns a string of stars for the previous line, the next line is always that string plus one more star.  So, your code would be something like:

```
public String printTriangle (int count) {
    if( count <= 0 ) return "";

    String p = printTriangle(count - 1);
    p = p + "*";
    System.out.println(p);

    return p;
 }
```

Comment: wow. I can't believe I didn't think of that. I think was thrown off because I assumed that is had to return void because it didn't make sense to return anything. Good job and thanks! Also, great explanation.

Comment: +1 Here is the right solution. Very clever! :-) One irrelevant improvement: the two print statements could be replaced by a single `System.out.println(p);`

Comment: +1 for being much more elegant than my solution :) nice use of the returned value.

Answer (score 7):

Example in python (just for the sake of prototyping, but I hope the idea gets through):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

def printTriangle(n):
    if n > 1:
        printTriangle(n - 1)
    # now that we reached 1, we can start printing out the stars 
    # as we climb out the stack ...
    print '*' * n

if __name__ == '__main__':
    printTriangle(5)
```

Output looks like this:

```
$ python 2717111.py
*
**
***
****
*****
```

Comment: I suspect that that would be considered iteration.

Comment: Although valid, this doesn't help much for java :)

Answer (score 3):

You can convert a loop to a recursive function like this:

```
void printStars(int count) {
    if (count == 0) return;

    System.out.print("*");
    printStars(count - 1);
}
printStars(5);    //Prints 5 stars
```

You should be able to make a similar function to print lines.

Comment: that prints out 1 line. the assignment is for a whole triangle in 1 method. That is why it is confusing me.

Comment: then you just need to figure out where to print the line break

Comment: You need to make a separate recursive function that calls `printStars`.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with this particular method. If we were allowed to use 2 methods for the solution there would be no problem. But we can only use 1. With this, I would need another method that calls printStars and then prints \n then increases the amount of stars printed for the next line--which isn't allowed.

Comment: I see; I hadn't realized that.  You can make the method take two parameters – `starCount` and `lineCount` – and call itself for the next line after it finishes the current line.

Comment: The question says that it has to be called like printTriangle(5) which sort of rules out having 2 parameters.

Comment: As Eyal posted, argument/method overloading solves this problem, but it is a bit of a stretch. We will see.

Answer (score 2):

You can also do it with a single (not so elegant) recursion,as follows:

```
public static void printTriangle (int leftInLine, int currLineSize, int leftLinesCount) {
    if (leftLinesCount == 0)
        return;
    if (leftInLine == 0){ //Completed current line?
        System.out.println();
        printTriangle(currLineSize+1, currLineSize+1, leftLinesCount-1);
    }else{
        System.out.print("*");
        printTriangle(leftInLine-1,currLineSize,leftLinesCount);
    }
}

public static void printTriangle(int size){
    printTriangle(1, 1, size);
}
```

The idea is that the method params represent the complete drawing state.

Note that size must be greater than 0.

Comment: For the sake of understanding simple recursion, it could be clearer to use a recursive helper method for printing each line.  This works too, though. :)

Comment: Thanks, this works. I was afraid I might have to go a multiple argument method because my professor keeps telling me how bad overloading methods is (I think it is pretty useful). I hope he accepts this. @Justin is HAS to be one method. This is stretching it but it is close enough.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

The method gets the number of stars as a parameter. Let's call it n.

Then it:

1. calls itself recursively with n-1.
2. prints a line with n stars.

Make sure to do nothing if n == 0.

Comment: Printing a line with n stars involves iteration unless defined recursively separately.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
 void ll__(int x){
  char static c = '0'; // character c will determine when to put newline
  if(!x){
    if(c=='1'){
      cout<<'\n';
    }
    return;
  }
  if(c=='0'){
    ll__(x-1); //  rows to be called in the stack and differentiated by character '0'
  }
  if(x==1 && c=='0'){
   cout<<'*';
  }else{  // columns to be printed in every row as per the row number in the stack
   c = '1';
   ll__(x-1);
   cout<< '*';
  }
}

int main(){
//writes code here
 ll__(5);
 exit(0);
}
```

Comment: Please include some description to code answers

Answer (score 0):

I found that the best way do this was:

```java
    public static void printTriangle(int x) {
        if(x == 0) {
            return;
        }
        printTriangle(x-1);
        printStars(x);
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

I think this should work... untested off the top of my head.

```
public void printTriangle(int count)
{    
    if (count == 0) return;
    printTriangle(count - 1);
    for (int x = 1; x <= count; x++) { 
        System.out.print("*"); 
    }
    System.out.print("\n"); 
}
```

Comment: -1 The OP asked for **a recursive method (without ANY iteration)**.

Comment: Ya I didn't notice the 'any iteration' part... I also didn't think you could use more than one method though but the accept answer did :(

Comment: well, method overloading is as close as I think we are going to get.

Answer (score -1):

So, you need to create a small block. What information does that block need? Just the maximum. But the recursion needs to know what line its on... you end up with a constructor like:

```
public void printTriangle (int current, int max)
```

Now, use that to put the rest of the recursion together:

```
public void printTriangle (int current, int max)
{ 
    if (current <= max) 
    { 
         // Draw the line of stars...
         for (int x=0; x<current; x++)
         {
             System.out.print("*")
         }
         // add a newline
         System.out.print("\n"); 

         // Do it again for the next line, but make it 1-bigger
         printTriangle(current + 1, max);
    } 
}
```

Now, all you have to do, is initiate it:

```
printTriangle(1, 5);
```

Comment: but it has iteration. It needs to have absolutely no iteration.

Comment: Ah.. Missed that part. In that case, you would just need to have a second iterative function ... although the one marked as "answered" is pretty darned clever.

Answer (score -1):

```
package playground.tests;

import junit.framework.TestCase;

public class PrintTriangleTest extends TestCase {
    public void testPrintTriangle() throws Exception {
        assertEquals("*\n**\n***\n****\n*****\n", printTriangleRecursive(5, 0, 0));
    }

    private String printTriangleRecursive(int count, int line, int character) {
        if (line == count)
            return "";
        if (character > line)
            return "\n" + printTriangleRecursive(count, line + 1, 0);
        return "*" + printTriangleRecursive(count, line, character + 1);
    }

}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
    void trianglePrint(int rows){
            int static currentRow = 1;
            int static currentStar = 1;

            // enter new line in this condition
            // (star > currentrow)  

            if (currentStar > currentRow ){
                currentStar = 1;
                currentRow++;
                cout << endl;
            }

            if (currentRow > rows){
                return; // finish
            }

            cout << "*";
            currentStar++;

            trianglePrint(rows);
        }
```

Comment: actually ,This is in C++  :")

Comment: you can use the same concept with any other language ;)

Answer (score -1):

i think this should do it

```
public void printTriangle (int count) {
   if(count >= 0) {
      printTriangle(count-1);
          for(int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
              System.out.print("*" + " ");
          }
      System.out.println(); 
   }
}
```

Comment: It is still iterative

Answer (score -1):

package com. company;

```
    public class practise7 { 
    static void star1(int n){
            if(n>0){
                for(int i = 0; i<n; i++){
    
                    System.out.print("*");
                }
                System.out.println("");
                star1(n-1);
            }
    
        }
      public static void main(String[] args) {
    star1(4); 
}
}
```

to forward star pattern

```
package com. company;
        
        public class practise7 { 
        static void star1(int n){
                if(n>0){
                    star1(n-1);
                    for(int i = 0; i<n; i++){
        
                        System.out.print("*");
                    }
                    System.out.println("");
                    
                }
        
            }
          public static void main(String[] args) {
        star1(4); 
    }
    }
```

Comment: can you please leave a comment describing your solution (and why it is better than the previous ones)?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).