# How to Print a Triangle using single variable and in a single loop?

Tags: c#, printing, geometry

A colleague ask me to print a triangle (of any shape) using a single variable and in a single loop. I do it this way:

**Program.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace Triangle
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            var triangle = "*";
            do { Console.WriteLine(triangle); }
            while ((triangle += "*").Length < 10);

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

I hope there must be a better way of doing this. You know one?

**EDIT:**

> *Tim ask me how about print a triangle without using variable and loop. Ouch!
>   I thought and still thinking :) you
>   know how it can be done?*

Comment: Seems reasonable. A challenge to print a triangle with no loops and/or no variables might be more fun :)

Comment: Tim yah that will be more fun :)

Comment: @Tim nah that would be too easy: `WriteLine("*\r\n**\r\n***");`

Comment: "Print a triangle using as many loops and variables as possible"

Comment: [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2717111/create-a-triangle-out-of-stars-using-only-recursion/2717254#2717254) is a solution to printing a triangle without using loops (with recursion).

Comment: `WriteLine("▲");`

Comment: Does your colleague also assign book reports?

Comment: Blorgbeard, you got a real sense of humor :) I ask this question to an intern he showed me a java statement that using drawing package to print a triangle in a single statement. This tell me this guy got talent in management skills. try to solve problem from out of box :)

Answer (score 2):

Do parameters count as variables?

```
Console.WriteLine(
    Enumerable.Range(2, 9)
              .Aggregate("*", (s, i) => s + Environment.NewLine + new string('*', i)));
```

Comment: This absolutely fine, dude :)

Answer (score 1):

I like your solution, why do you need a better way?

Personally, I'd have gone with a while loop instead:

```
        var triangle = "";
        while ((triangle += "*").Length < 10)
            Console.WriteLine(triangle);
```

But that doesn't change much.

Comment: Thats much better, Setephen :) Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Use Recursion to eliminate loops - you still need a variable.

OTTOMH (plus haven't coded C# in a loooooooong time)

```
bool PrintLine(int NumStars)
{
 Console.WriteLine(space(NumStars).Replace (" ", "*"));
 if (NumStars < 20)
  PrintLine (NumStars);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Process.Start("http://www.google.com/images?q=triangle");
```

Answer (score 0):

No loop, no variable (you get the idea)

```
Console.WriteLine("*");
Console.WriteLine("**");
Console.WriteLine("***");
Console.WriteLine("****");
Console.WriteLine("*****");
```

Meets the requirements. ;)

Comment: you live in a very smart world.