# Array reference recursion

Tags: java, arrays, recursion

I have a problem with my 2D Array recursion. It should print this

```
*
**
***
****
*****
```

but I get only this:

```
*****
*****
*****
*****
*****
```

I think it's because I write to the same array everytime and overwrite the old results. Here is my code:

```
public class filleArrayRec {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[][] array = new String[5][5];

        fillArr(array, 0);

        for (String[] i : array) {
            for (String j : i) {
                System.out.print(j);
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }

    private static void fillArr(String[][] array, int index) {
        if (index < array.length) {
            array[index] = fillArrayLine(array[index], 0);
        } else {
            return;
        }

        fillArr(array, index+1);
    }

    private static String[] fillArrayLine(String[] array, int index) {
        if (index < array.length) {
            array[index] = "*";
        } else {
            return array;
        }

        return fillArrayLine(array, index+1);
    }

}
```

Comment: `(index < array.length)` array.length is always constant (5) in your case

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Create a triangle out of stars using only recursion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2717111/create-a-triangle-out-of-stars-using-only-recursion)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you initialize your `array` with `new String[5][5]`, all calls to `fillArrayLine` end up passing a five-element array, thus filling a square.

Replace initialization with `new String[5][]`, and set `array[i]` as you go:

```
array[index] = fillArrayLine(new String[index+1], 0);
```

Comment: wow thanks for your solution!