# printing star pattern without using recursion using only a single loop?

Tags: java

I made a program

```
public class StarPattern2 {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        printStar("*", 1, 5);
    }

    public static void printStar(String s, int i, int a) {
        if (a == 0)
            return;
        for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
            System.out.print(s);
        }
        System.out.println();
        a--;
        i++;
        printStar("*", i, a);
    }

}
```

to print the pattern as

```
*
**
***
****
*****
```

but it is using a one loop i dont want to use any loop i.e. by using recursion only i want to print the pattern.

Comment: Do you want a single loop to print out the pattern or do you want to print it out by recursion? Because the title differs from your last sentence, therefore it's unclear to me.

Comment: i actually want one iteration..it can be either by using one loop or using recursion without using loop.

Comment: I think, the variable `i` has no use in this method. It should stop the for-loop, but since `i` and `j` grow at the same speed, the `if(a == 0) ... return` part stops the loop, not the `i`. Therefore you only need the `a` which corresponds to the number of rows.

Answer (score 1):

To remove the recursion, replace printStar with:

```
public static void  printStar(String s, int i, int a)
{
   for(;a>0;a--)
   {
     for(int j=0;j<i;j++)
     {
      System.out.print(s);
     }
     System.out.println();

     i++;
   }
}
```

For the changed requirement of either recursion, OR loop:

```
public static void  printStar(String s, int i, int a)
{
    if(a == 0) return;

    System.out.println(s);

    printStar(s+"*", i, a-1);
}
```

Note that the i variable isnt needed any longer.

Answer (score 0):

You maybe do like this:

```
public class App {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        App app = new App();
        app.printTriangle(5);
    }

    public String printTriangle(int count) {
        if (count <= 0) return "";
        String p = printTriangle(count - 1);
        p = p + "*";
        System.out.println(p);
        return p;
    }

}

// Result
// *
// **
// ***
// ****
// *****
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2717254/1368690 ... this solution might be correct, altough I am unsure what the variables `i` and `a` are for in OPs question.

Comment: it should be without string concatenation.

Answer (score 0):

When you want do do this by loop, then this could be what you want:

```
public static void printStar(String s, int lines) {
  for (int i = 0; i < lines; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j <= i; j++) {
      System.out.print(s);
    }
    System.out.println();
  }
}
```

or alternatively, with only one loop:

```
public static void printStar(String s, int lines) {
  String out = "";
  for (int i = 0; i < lines; i++) {
    out += s;
    System.out.println(out);
  }
}
```